# java hibernate netbeans xml

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, netbeans-6.9, derby

When i am using net beans to develop one standalone swing application which is transacting with derby database. In my database i dont have any ID field all columns are nullable but when i am mapping my abc.hbm.xml file and validating it is givin following error:-
The content of element type "class" must match "(meta*,subselect?,cache?,synchronize*,comment?,tuplizer*,(id|composite-id),discriminator?,natural-id?,(version|timestamp)?,(property|many-to-one|one-to-one|component|dynamic-component|properties|any|map|set|list|bag|idbag|array|primitive-array)*,((join*,subclass*)|joined-subclass*|union-subclass*),loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,filter*,resultset*,(query|sql-query)*)". [20]

Can anybody help me out with this error.

Cant we map that xml without having ID field in table???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML is invalid, because it doesn't conform to the hibernate DTD. As the error message says, every class element must have either one id sub-element, or one composite-id sub-element.

A hibernate entity must have an ID (simple or composite). Your database schema deosn't seem very clean. You should have a primary key in every table.